# How does Pandas DataFrame reindex function work with the Copy Parameter when it is set to 'False'?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, copy, reindex

I could not quite understand the functionality of copy using reindex. When I tested, copy=False is working only if I am giving exactly same index/columns, in sequence. But this not work if I am changing the sequence of columns/indexes

Statement in Pandas documentation says:

"A new object is produced unless the new index is equivalent to the current one and copy=False.

**Actual Code ::**

```
dataframe_obj1 = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(16).reshape(4,4), index = [0,1,2,3], columns = [0,1,2,3])
dataframe_obj1_reindex_copy_False = dat.reindex([3,2,1,0], copy=False)
dataframe_obj1.iloc[0,0] = 500
print("""original dataframe - "dataframe_obj1" after reindexing applied is as below""")
print(dataframe_obj1)
print('\n')
print("""re-indexed dataframe - "dataframe_obj1_reindex_copy_False" is  as below""")
print(dataframe_obj1_reindex_copy_False)
```

**Result:**

```
original dataframe - "dataframe_obj1" after reindexing applied is as below
     0   1   2   3
0  500   1   2   3
1    4   5   6   7
2    8   9  10  11
3   12  13  14  15


re-indexed dataframe - "dataframe_obj1_reindex_copy_False" is  as below
    0   1   2   3
3  12  13  14  15
2   8   9  10  11
1   4   5   6   7
0   5   1   2   3
```

**Expecting:**

So was expecting value of 500 to get reflected in original data frame as well. But its not happening.

Can someone guide me on this ?

And I guess in case we want to maintain the sequence same and copy=False, how could that be a significant use case as we can achieve it through simple assignment to another variable

Comment: what's `dat` in your code? if I change that to `dataframe_obj1`, then it works as expected, modify one dataframe will modify the other

Comment: "Statement in Pandas documentation says: "A new object is produced unless the new index is equivalent to the current one and copy=False." - okay, so *what don't you understand* about this? Did something happen when you ran the code, that was *different from what you expected*? if so, what did you think should happen instead, and what is your reasoning?

Comment: @QuangHoang - Its not dat actually, its the same original dataframe object - "dataframe_obj1" which I meant in the code. But anyways I corrected it. And I am not getting the expected result as you said. By running the mentioned code steps in my post.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel - From the point, what I understood Is, if we assign to a variable, the result of reindex function by keeping copy=False along with same indexes/columns, and by the term equivalent I understood that, index/columns position can be changed but adding or removing is not allowed.  So in this case no new object is created but the reference is passed to result variable. But that is not happening as per my code and result mentioned above, The changes made in one object are reflected in other only if sequence of index/columns are also same ?So its absolutely same as aliasing ?

Comment: If you change the code, you should rerun it and update the output. For me, the updated value shows on both dataframes. To answer your question: **Yes**, that's correct, in terms of underlying data at least. You still get too dataframe objects with different indexes. The indexes are **equivalent** but NOT **identical**.

Comment: Hi @QuangHoang - Please verify the updated

Comment: Hi @QuangHoang or someone, could you please help with this point ?